# React, mapping over a medium-complex json Object to get the keys inside of messages

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express, fetch

I need to take a json Object that looks like this that I fetch from my api that request's from zoom's Oauth api.

```
{
  "date": "2019-09-17",
  "page_size": 10,
  "next_page_token": "",
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "F3CbafdljsfjkdfgBA7",
      "message": "And you?",
      "sender": "myemail@someemailaddr.com",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:25:21Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751921626
    },
    {
      "id": "B0DbfdgdfhAAfgf237000",
      "message": "I am good",
      "sender": "myemail@someemailaddr.com",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:25:17Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751917976
    },
    {
      "id": "C9Bbdfgd4sad301",
      "message": "How are you",
      "sender": "myfriendsemail@someemailaddr.us",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:24:13Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751853297
    },
    {
      "id": "769fgdgdfgfd4566F7B96665",
      "message": "hello",
      "sender": "myfriendsemail@someemailaddr.us",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:22:26Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751746769
    }
  ]
}
```

and I really just care about mapping over the message and sender fields. This is the first time I've worked with JSON objects however, and I'm kind of stuck on it. I've bounced around quite a few of the forums, and while a lot of items look promising, perhaps I'm just just not getting the concept. I'm usually a UI/UX guy, and having troubles interacting with building/working with a multiple API request to get the data I want in the format I want.

Comment: How do you want the structure of your final data to look?

Comment: If it is just an array with simply messages:message, I can work with that. Or even just the messages array in total.

Comment: What are you having troubles with exactly? Where's the code where you attempt to map over the `JSON` response? Utilize `JSON.parse` to turn this `JSON` response into a plain object then work with it as you normally work with objects inside `JavaScript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify each element of an array, you should use the `Array.map` function:

```js
function parseArray(arr) {
  return arr.map((messageObject) => {
    return {
      message: messageObject.message,
      sender: messageObject.sender,
    };
  });
}

const input = {
  "date": "2019-09-17",
  "page_size": 10,
  "next_page_token": "",
  "messages": [{
      "id": "F3CbafdljsfjkdfgBA7",
      "message": "And you?",
      "sender": "myemail@someemailaddr.com",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:25:21Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751921626
    },
    {
      "id": "B0DbfdgdfhAAfgf237000",
      "message": "I am good",
      "sender": "myemail@someemailaddr.com",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:25:17Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751917976
    },
    {
      "id": "C9Bbdfgd4sad301",
      "message": "How are you",
      "sender": "myfriendsemail@someemailaddr.us",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:24:13Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751853297
    },
    {
      "id": "769fgdgdfgfd4566F7B96665",
      "message": "hello",
      "sender": "myfriendsemail@someemailaddr.us",
      "date_time": "2019-09-17T20:22:26Z",
      "timestamp": 1568751746769
    }
  ]
};

console.log(parseArray(input.messages));
```